# Which temporary projection is most suitable for calculating a buffer around a route

Tags: coordinate-system, buffer, proj, nettopologysuite

To create a buffer around route (for purpose of querying around a route), I figured I need to:

1. convert route points from geographic to planar coordinates
2. calculate a buffer
3. convert result back to geographic coordinates

My question is which temporary projection is most suitable for calculating a buffer around a route?

I narrowed it down to two probable candidates: a dynamic **Lambert azimuthal equal area** or a custom **transverse Mercator** projection based on route's center point.

Routes will be up to few 1000 km long. Smallest buffer distance will be 100 m from route and largest buffer 5 km from route.

Comment: Where is your route? The best projection depends largely on location. If your focus is on distance, you should pick a projection that prioritizes distances.

Comment: Routes will be located mostly in Europe. Focus is finding POIs along a route. (eg. POIs up to 2 km from route)

Comment: Have you considered the  [Oblique Mercator](https://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/geocalc/classdef/projection/projections/oblique_mercator_azimuth.htm) projection?

Comment: @JimT Yes (after I posted this question). But I'm not sure how to calculate the average azimuth of the route. I tried to calculate linear regression from route points, but the resulting slope is incorrect. The error is I think because I used degrees (lon, lat) in calculation. I should probably convert coordinates to projected coordinate system before calculating slope with linear regression. A projection that preserves angles (Mercator I think). Is there a better way to calculate an average azimuth of the route (to be used to create Oblique Mercator)?

Comment: EDIT: I made a mistake. Not Mercator projection, but probably Azimuthal Equidistant or Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection for calculating slope with linear regression.

Comment: I figured it out how to calculate linear regression using geographic coordinates. Instead of converting slope directly to azimuth, I use slope to calculate position of a second point (these two points give avg. angle line). latDelta = slope*lonDelta. This way no projection of coordinates for linear regression calculation is needed. Azimuth is calculated from these two points and then used to create Hotine Oblique Mercator projection.

Answer (score 0):

**Hotine Oblique Mercator** projection seems to be well suited for elongated routes, since central line of projection remains near the route.

Less so for circular routes, but the tradeoff seems good for my use case, where I expect that majority of routes will be more elongated.